Use AlpineJS data in django-cotton component
I'm trying to use AlpineJS jointly with django-cotton components. I tried the following but it did not work.
<div x-data="{ message: 'I ❤️ Alpine' }">
    <c-card x-bind:title="message"></c-card>
</div>


with django-cotton card component simply copied from django-cotton Quickstart.
<div>
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ slot }}</p>
</div>

Is there a way to achieve this?

cotton/card.html
<div>
  <h2 x-text="message"></h2>
  <p>{{ slot }}</p>
</div>

<div x-data="{ message: 'I ❤️ Alpine' }">
  <c-card >content slot here</c-card>
</div>

other method
<div {{attrs}}>
  <h2 x-text="message"></h2>
  <p>{{ slot }}</p>
</div>

<c-card x-data="{
  message: 'I ❤️ Alpine'
}">Some content</c-card>


Thx for your answer. It does work but I think it defeats the purpose of using django-cotton, where the data to be inserted in the component is directly defined in the call to this component...

I'm not sure when it comes to js data.

@kenshuri what exactly are you trying to achieve? What’s your use case? The point here is that you can have a predefined, prestyled component that can optionally receive any attribute, be it x-alpine, id, etc.
